# How to check the data in the csv file is a string or number or alphanumeric in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am learning data analysis using Python. I am successfully able to read the data and print the data of a csv file using Python. My mentor gave me a task to find out whether the data that is displaying is

- a string,
- a number, or
- alphanumeric.

Comment: It sounds like she or he is pointing you down the road of regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a variable `v` is a string, or number, you may look at the following:

```
>>> v = 'test'
>>> isinstance(v, str)
True
```

Or

```
>>> t = 2
>>> isinstance(p, int)
True
```

Now if it is a string and you want to check more precisely the content of that string (alpha, alphanumerical, digit, etc.) you can use the built-in python methods:

- [`str.isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum)
- [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)
- [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit)
- ...

Now try:

```
>>> v.isalnum()
True
>>> v.isalpha()
True
>>> v.isdigit()
False
>>> v.islower()
False
```

Comment: That is not clear enough. I don't know what you start from, what you get, neither what you'd want to get instead. Please format your question properly -- maybe within a new thread, it seems unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileName['ColumnName'][0].isdigit()
```

This will Check whether the First Value of the Specified Column is Digit or Not. From this, we can easily infer if it's a digit or not(Can even check for strings also)